# How to append json array response to the bootstrap table

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I have question regarding on my codes, I already have a result on my multiple array json response, The only problem is to append the result on the table.

On my response I want to append select_order_details to the table, how to use foreach to show all result and append the result to the table.
[image: response result]

**My Html:**

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%;">
<thead>
    <tr font-size: 14px; ">
        <th scope="col">Menu Image</th>
        <th scope="col">Menu Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Quantity</th>
        <th scope="col">Subtotal</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody style=" font-size:14px;">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

**My Ajax Function:**

```
    $('button#gather_customer_order').on('click',function()
  {
      var order_id = $(this).attr('data-order-id');
      var customer_id = $(this).attr('data-customer-id');



      $.ajax({
          url:'/customer_detail_ordering_logic',
          type:'GET',
          data:{order_id:order_id,customer_id:customer_id},
          success:function(response){

              var response_customer_id = response[0].customer_details_id[0].customer_id;
              var response_order_id = response[0].customer_details_id[0].order_id;

                $.ajax({
                    url:'/fetch_detail_order_monitor',
                    type:'GET',
                    data:{response_order_id:response_order_id,response_customer_id:response_customer_id},
                    success:function(res){


                       console.log(res);

                   var select_order_details = response[0].select_order_details[0];


                   $.each(select_order_details, function(index, el) {
                      //For example
                      console.log(index + el)

                  })



                    }
                })

          }
      })

  });
```

Response Result:
[image: response result]

Answer (score 0):

first of all you need to add `id` or `class` for result element, in this case you should do this:

```
<tbody style=" font-size:14px;">
<tr id="result">

</tr>
```

and then you can use `$.each` that it is like foreach, like this:

```
success:function(res){
    $.each(res, function(r){
       $("#result").append("<td>"+res[r].name+"</td><td>"+res[r].family+"</td><td>"+res[r].age+"</td>");
    });
});
```

and this should work for you (i didn't know what is your response back exactly, that's why i use the 'name, family,age' , you should do this for your response that get back from controller.

Comment: var select_order_details = response[0].select_order_details[0]; i use this, so to get the specific object then now, why only the first array only i get

Comment: please after `success:function(res)` write this command: `console.log(res)` , so you can see what is bring on here from your controller , maybe just one column is getting back to your ajax success

Answer (score 0):

```
var response=JSON.parse(res); var html=''; 
for(var i=0; i<response.length; i++){
    html+="<tr><td>"+response[i].attribute+"</td>"+<td>"+response[i].attribute2+"</td>+ <td>"+response[i].attribute3+"</td>+<td>"+response[i].attribute4+"</td></tr>"; } $('.table').append(html);
```